# Select dentro do where deixando a consulta muito lenta?

Tags: mysql, query, select

Tenho a seguinte estrutura:

[image: Tabelas relacionadas na consulta]

E minha query está dessa forma

```
SELECT tbl_nfes.*, count(tbl_nfe_itens.pedido > 0) as v, tbl_nfe_itens.status FROM 
tbl_nfes
INNER JOIN tbl_nfe_itens ON tbl_nfes.nfe = tbl_nfe_itens.nfe
INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_nfes.id_user = tbl_users.id
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_nfe_itens WHERE position = 0 AND nfe = tbl_nfe_itens.nfe ) = 0
GROUP BY tbl_nfes.nfe ORDER BY tbl_nfes.nfe ASC
```

**Removendo** o select dentro do where a consulta não demora em mostrar o resultado, porém carrega dados que não são aceitos, só poderia retornar as NFEs que todos os itens possuam `position = 0`. O que devo fazer para que esta consulta se torne mais eficaz?

Comment: O estrnho que dessa forma ele traz o resultado que desejo que eh mostrar apenas as nfs onde todos os seus itens tenham `position = 0` já tentei colocar `where tbl_nfe_itens.position = 0` e ele carrega as nfs que tenham ao menos um item com `position = 0`, tem outra forma de fazer carregar apenas se todos os ítens tiverem `position = 0`?

Comment: Desculpa faltou uma parte do where já editei, faltou `AND nfe = tbl_nfe_itens.nfe

Comment: Sim foi na hora de transcrever a query, mas já coloquei a `,`

Comment: Execute essa `query` para criar um indice e teste novamente sua consulta `CREATE INDEX tbl_nfe_itens_nfe ON tbl_nfe_itens(nfe);`

Comment: Perfeito funcionou muito bem, estou tentando achar algum material para eu entender como funcionam os indices. muito obrigado.

Comment: Show @Sorak agradeço pela disponibilidade e se puder postar a resposta ira ajudar muitas pessoas e eu poderia entender melhor.

Comment: Cuidado com subquery em where. Lembre-se que a subquery será executada para cada linha encontrada. Imagine o impacto em uma pesquisa com uma fonte de milhões de registros. Criar índice é um contorno que pode aliviar momentaneamente. Use com parcimônia.

Answer (score 1):

Execute a query abaixo:

```
SELECT tbl_nfes.*,
       count(tbl_nfe_itens.pedido > 0) AS v,
       tbl_nfe_itens.status
FROM tbl_nfes
    INNER JOIN tbl_nfe_itens ON tbl_nfes.nfe = tbl_nfe_itens.nfe
    INNER JOIN tbl_users ON tbl_nfes.id_user = tbl_users.id
GROUP BY tbl_nfes.nfe
HAVING COUNT(case when tbl_nfe_itens.POSITION =0 then 1 end )=0
ORDER BY tbl_nfes.nfe ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

Seu WHERE está estranho, veja que ele compara um numero COUNT(*) com outro numero (?) e pode ser o por esse motivo que ele deixa a consulta lenta.. Acredito que ele deveria estar fazendo uma comparação com o valor de alguma coluna.

```
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_nfe_itens WHERE position = 0 ) = 0
```